# Codeigniter on Nginx not loading all resource

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, server, config, linode

I've setup nginx and imported codeigniter into my projects and I'm unable to resolve the following error.My server is running Ubuntu 16 and php7 I've tried giving the files permission but still no solution. Anyone know where the problem could be? Thanks

My default config file for my server in nginx.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/observum/site;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name 45.79.4.55;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }




    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE704.jpg)

Comment: Soory I mean my project is done in codeigniter*

Answer (score 0):

you css/js path is incorrect,its include from 'site' directory

its getting include in your document is

`http://45.79.4.55/site/libreriasJS/boceto/css/modern-business.css`

but its should be like

`http://45.79.4.55/libreriasJS/boceto/css/modern-business.css`

Comment: this>>>>>>>
//$config['base_url'] = '';

$site_url = '/site/'; 

$config['base_url'] = '/site/';
//$config['site_base_url'] = '/stream/';
$config['site_base_url'] = '/';